# Create master detail page withing page-loader

Tags: php, master-detail

So i made a website which its pages are loaded trough a page loader within the index.php file. Now i wanted to create a master detail page but i cant get it working correctly. it will redirect to the detail.php file but it doesnt do anything with the ID from $_GET['id'].

```
//detail .php
<?php
if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id=mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
}
?>

<form action="" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <center><table>
    <?php   
       global $connect;
       echo "TEST"
    ?>
    </table></center>
</form>

//pageloader.php
<?php
if(@$_GET["page"]){
    $page = "pages/".$_GET["page"].".php";
    if(file_exists($page))
    {
      include $page;
    }
    else 
    {
      echo "deze pagina bestaat niet";
    }
}
?>
```

When i click on a link that refers to the ID it gives this link:

.../?page=details?id=6

this results into page does not exist.

How can i resolve this little problem to properly display the content of the given ID.

Comment: You could stop doing that. Since You're open to LFI (Local File Inclusion) and basically will be allowing anybody (that has some knowledge) to find your `/etc/passwd` file and various other files.

Comment: Well there is not much to find, it is just a very small website for my dads antique shop. i want to show products and when you click on them you get to see the details. Do you have an other option in mind to use?

Comment: You should set up a whitelist as I detailed in my answer :) just to make sure they aren't trying to include any dodgy things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't favour this type of "dynamic page" sort of deal you have going on here, but if you're going to do it this way, then you should run it against a white list.

```
$allowed = array(
    '1' => 'page1.php',
    '2' => 'page2.php',
    .....etc
);

$id = trim($_GET['id']);
if(isset($allowed[$id]) && file_exist("pages/".$allowed[$id].".php")) {
    include("pages/" . $allowed[$id] . ".php";);
}
```

The above checks to ensure that the `$id` is present in the `$allowed` array of pages and if the file exists in it's directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
$id=intval($_GET['id']);
```

`intval` will qualify the id as numeric and will produce a zero if blank or non-numeric.

`mysqli_real_escape_string` is used to escape text before storing it in a record

Change

```
if(@$_GET["page"]){
  $page = '/page
```

To

```
$page = $_GET["page"];
if strlen($page) > 0){
    $page = "/home/user/public_html/pages/$page.php";
    if (file_exists($page)){
```

There is no reason to use the dot string concatenation when double quotes are used.

It's better to retrieve the page from the local directory than HTTP

The address bar will look cleaner if you use post rather than get

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

The use `$_POST['page'];`

`<center>` is obsolete, use CSS instead.

```
<style>
table{margin:0 auto;}
</style>
```